# How do blur points when it is not selected by a filter in ArcGIS?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis-js-api

I want to implement a filter to be able to blur all points on my map.

```
 const nzgdFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "url...",
      definitionExpression:"",
    });

    nzgdFeatureLayer
      .when(() => {
        view.whenLayerView(nzgdFeatureLayer).then((layerView) => {
           nzgdFeatureLayer.featureEffect = new FeatureEffect({
            filter: new FeatureFilter({
            where: " 1=1 ",
           }),
           excludedEffect: "blur(3px) ",
           });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    
    webmap.layers.push(nzgdFeatureLayer);
```

Is there a way to change the blur value of each point when I haven't done selecting it?

Comment: How are you selecting the features?, what is the condition?